# Backspace in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a function something like the following:

```
Function Replace(source As String, typeText As String)
    If Trim(Selection.Text) = Trim(source) Then
    Selection.typeText Text:=typeText
    End If
End Function
```

I run a long list of Call Replace lines, but occasionally, I need to type a backspace or two before the replacement text. For example if I have [therefore] highlighted in "She was cold, therefore, she put on a jacket," then I need to replace [therefore] with [; therefore,].

```
With Selection
    Call Replace("therefore", "; therefore,")
End with
```

Obviously, this is leaving two incorrect commas and a space.

Comment: Why not expand the selection?

Comment: Selection.MoveStart wdCharacter, -2

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you asked, pretty dirty though

```
Sub SomeSub()

    Dim MyString As String

                        'therefore is case sensitive
    If Selection.Text = "therefore" Then

        Selection.MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-2
        Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

        MyString = Selection

        If InStr(String1 = MyString, String2 = ",") = 1 And _
            InStrRev(String1 = MyString, String2 = ",") = 1 Then

            'changin text to requirmeent
            Selection.typeText "therefore"
            Selection.MoveLeft wdWord, 1, wdExtend
        Else
            'resetting original selection
            Selection.MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
            Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1

        End If

        With Selection
            Call Replace("therefore", "; therefore,")
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```